# Rails 3, HABTM how to query with conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have Awards and Categories, joined with Awards_Categories

I have 2 Categories.

I need to find all the Awards that have Category.id = 1, but not Category.id =2.  Some categories have one or the other, some have just one.  I want a list of the Awards that have category 1 but not category 2.

I have a  scope:

```
scope :in_categories, lambda { |categories|
      joins(:categories).
      where(:awards_categories => { :category_id => categories } ).
      select("DISTINCT awards.*")
    }
```

And this works with a query like:

```
@awardsall = Award.in_categories([1 && 2]).order("name ASC")
```

I have tried

```
@awards_store = Award.in_categories([1]).order("name ASC")
```

With:

```
<% @awards_store.each do |store| %> 
        <li><%= link_to store.name, award_path(store), :title => store.info %> | 
        <% store.categories.each do |cat| %>
            <%= cat.id%>
        <% end %>
    </li>
<% end %>
```

EDIT---
I know the block is not what I need. it is just my attempt at finding a way to make it work.

And while this lists all the awards, and all the award categories its still grabbing awards that have category.id = 2 because some awards have both

any ideas?

Comment: Anyone? still need help if anyone knows how to get this to work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, didn't test it, but the main idea is to count the rows in the connecting table.

```
scope :in_categories, lambda { |*categories|
      joins(:categories).
      where(:awards_categories => { :category_id => categories } ).
      where("(select count(distinct category_id) from awards_categories where category_id in (?)) = ?", categories, categories.size)
    }
```

and use it this way:

```
@awardsall = Award.in_categories(1, 2).order("name ASC") 

@awards_store = Award.in_categories(1).order("name ASC")
```

If you have a model for awards_categories, then it will look better:

```
scope :in_categories, lambda { |*categories|
      joins(:categories).
      where(:awards_categories => { :category_id => categories } ).
      where("#{AwardCategory.where(:category_id => categories).count("distinct category_id").to_sql}=#{categories.size}")
    }
```